# Get-ADUser missing msExch attributes when using filter all

Tags: powershell, exchange-2010

I'm a domain admin trying to create an export of all AD users, recording all msExch attributes (Exchange 2010).

The following works fine:

```
Get-ADUser <sAMAccountName> -Properties * | Select name, *msexch*
```

The following doesn't:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Select name, *msexch*
```

Instead I get a column named *msexch* with no value

What am I missing?

Comment: What version of powershell are you using?

Comment: Version 5.0. I'm pretty sure I'm good on that front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work after you add the searchbased to narrow down on your scope.
Get-ADUser -searchbase "OU=ParentOU,OU=All Users,DC=domain.DC=local" -Filter * -Properties * | Select name, *msexch*

I find similar issues as you if a searchbase is not specified while your filter is wild open "eg. *"

Comment: Nice one thanks. This does the job although interestingly, if you pipe through to sort, it excludes the attributes once again. No issue though as filtering can be done in Excel regardless.